# Why am I getting `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)` on save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-3, ruby-3.1

I have this method that gives me a error `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)` after upgrading to ruby 3.1 at `test.save!`.

```
    def seed_test_program
      test = TestProgram.find_or_initialize_by(
        name: "Program",
        code: :program
      )
      test.metadata["status_types"] = [
        "enrolled", "excluded", "rejected", "not_enrolled"
      ]
      test.metadata["status_reasons"] = {
        "excluded" => [
          "reason 1",
          "reason 2",
          "reason 3"
        ],
        'rejected' => [
          "reason 1",
          "reason 2",
          "reason 3"
        ],
        "not_enrolled" => [
          "reason 1",
          "reason 2",
          "other"
        ]
      }
      test.save!
      Test.program.reload
    end
```

I have tried

```
      test = TestProgram.find_or_initialize_by({
        name: "Program",
        code: :program
      })
```

and

```
      options = {
        name: "Program",
        code: :program
      }
     TestProgram.find_or_initialize_by(**options)
```

(this method is called as follows `Seeds::TestProgram.seed` where the seed function contains `seed_test_program`)

but it keeps giving me the same error. How do I fix this?

Stack Trace

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
/**/app/services/seeds/test_programs.rb:138:in `seed_test_program'
/**/app/services/seeds/test_programs.rb:18:in `seed'
/**/app/services/seeds/test_programs.rb:9:in `initialize'
/**/app/services/seeds/test_programs.rb:5:in `new'
/**/app/services/seeds/test_programs.rb:5:in `seed'
/**/db/seeds.rb:51:in `<main>'
/**/db/sample_data/test_environment.rb:13:in `<main>'
/**/lib/tasks/sample_data.rake:6:in `block (4 levels) in <main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:reset => db:setup => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Test Programs

```
module Seeds
  class TestPrograms

    def self.seed
      self.new
    end

    def initialize
      seed
    end

    private

    def seed
     seed_test_program
    end

    def seed_test_program
      test = TestProgram.find_or_initialize_by(
        name: "Program",
        code: :program
      )
      test.metadata["status_types"] = [
        "enrolled", "excluded", "rejected", "not_enrolled"
      ]
      test.metadata["status_reasons"] = {
        "excluded" => [
          "reason 1",
          "reason 2",
          "reason 3"
        ],
        'rejected' => [
          "reason 1",
          "reason 2",
          "reason 3"
        ],
        "not_enrolled" => [
          "reason 1",
          "reason 2",
          "other"
        ]
      }
      test.save!
      Test.program.reload
    end
  end
end
```

Seeds.rb

```
# Seed Test Programs
Seeds::TestPrograms.seed
```

Comment: Add the full stack trace to your question.

Comment: Sure added @smathy

Comment: pls show the line in the code that *calls* the `seed_test_program` method. I'm guessing it's calling with an argument, but the method does not require an argument.

Comment: Added more info @LesNightingill

Comment: what is the column type of the 'code' column in the 'test_programs' table?

Comment: ```
CREATE TABLE public.test_programs (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying NOT NULL,
    code character varying NOT NULL,
    metadata jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb
);
```

Comment: @LesNightingill it is character varying

Comment: well I don't know the answer... so how to diagnose? Start removing things and see where the error disappears. I would firstly remove the two statements that set the metadata column. Still fails? Change `:program` to `"program"`. Still fails? Try `TestProgram.find_by` iso `find_or_initialize_by`. etc... keep reducing until the error goes away, then the last thing you did was causing the error!

Comment: And you're sure line 138 is the `test.save!` line?

Comment: Why are you trying to instantiate a class in a class method? That has a bad smell. Why do you need to initialize TestPrograms at all? Just make `seed` be a class method and call it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Bizarrely it works if you do

```
test = TestProgram.find_or_create_by(
        name: "Program",
        code: :program
      )
```